# How to properly run Snipe-it from Sub folder in WAMP?

Tags: php, wamp

Trying to run Snipe-IT asset management software on my WAMP install.

I extracted Snipe-IT in one a subfolder 
C:/WorkFolder/Projects/Client_A/www/snipe-it

I have an Apache alias setup for "projects" that points to C:/WorkFolder/Projects

that way i can just go to browser and type http://localhost/projects to get to my different projects and their respective resource and public (www) folders.

So obviously i installed Snipe-IT for CLIENT A and it's located in:

C:/WorkFolder/Projects/Client_A/www/snipe-it/

I went through all the setup stuff but i can't seem to figure out how to set the virtual host right for this to make it run.

I've setup the following Virtual Host in http.conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>


    <Directory "C:/WorkFolder/Projects/Client_A/www/snipe-it/public">
        Allow From All
        AllowOverride All
        Options +Indexes
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    DocumentRoot "C:/WorkFolder/Projects/Client_A/www/snipe-it/public"
    ServerName "http://localhost/projects/Client_A/www/snipe-it/public"
    # Other directives here
</VirtualHost>
```

so now when go to the browser to access

"http://localhost/projects/Client_A/www/snipe-it/public" from my browser, i got a NOT FOUND error.

I also tried setting servername as follows: 
        ServerName "http://snipeit"

tried to visit that in the browser (http://snipeit), still not found .

How do i get snipe-it to run properly on WAMP and when accessed through a subfolder?

Really hoping for some help;

Answer (score 1):

Snipe-IT really wants to be run as a subdomain or on its own domain name. If you wish to run Snipe-IT in a subdirectory (https://yourserver.com/snipe-it) instead of at a primary domain (http://yourserver.com) or a sub-domain (https://snipe-it.yourserver.com), you'll need to go through the standard install steps 1-5, and then make a few small changes to your server configuration and .htaccess file.

1. Go to your WAMP install path then bin\apache\apache2.4.27\conf\extra
2. Open httpd-vhosts.conf
3. Comment the default VirtualHost
4. Add the Snipe-It VirtualHost

   `# Virtual Hosts
      #
      # <VirtualHost *:80>
      #   ServerName localhost
      #   ServerAlias localhost
      #   DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www"
      #   <Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/">
      #     Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
      #     AllowOverride All
      #     Require local
      #   </Directory>
      # </VirtualHost>
      <VirtualHost *:80>
         Alias /snipe-it "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/snipe-it/public/"
         <Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/snipe-it/public">
            Allow From All
            AllowOverride All
            Options +Indexes
            #Require all granted
         </Directory>
         DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/snipe-it/public"
         ServerName localhost/snipe-it
      </VirtualHost>`

You can replace ${INSTALL_DIR} with your WAMP path if you like but this will work perfectly

Now add the following line to your .htaccess inside the snipe-it public folder
Add it direct after RewriteEngine On

```
...
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /snipe-it
...
```

For More information [WAMP](https://snipe-it.readme.io/v4.0/docs/wamp) & [Subdirectories](https://snipe-it.readme.io/docs/subdirectories)